# Child Site doesn't appear in the Network menu

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain-mapping

As you see in the snapshot, just the main site appear in My Sites menu, Although it appears correctly in the "Network Admin".

I used the subdomain installation when I configured the Wordpress MU.
And this is the Wordpress MU part in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

[image: just the main site appearing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution , it's dead simple, I should add myself to the child site as a user, I guess this should be done by default.